# Dynamically manage overlapping element visibility like Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, design-patterns

I am currently building a Google Calendar clone app in Reactjs, so far it is working fine.

I reached the final stage of this project I started thinking on how to make overlapping elements visible.

This scenario applies to events in the calendar for one or multiple users.

Each column is an array of timestamps.

```
let day = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I am able to get the range for each array like so:

```
let event1 = [2,3,4,5]
let event2 = [3,4]
let event3 = [3]
let event4 = [3]
let event5 = [6,7]
let event6 = [5,6]
```

Is there a method I could use to approach this or a custom library?

Desired outcome:

[image: desider outcome]

Comment: What is your desired outcome? What logic are you using to consider an element visible now?

Comment: I want to resize the width of elements like Google Calendar does @gqstav

Comment: OK. Right now you have some array with integers with incoming values. What are the desired outgoing values? Or what components do you have, forming your application?

Comment: @gqstav the day array represents a series of divs. The other arrays represent events in those divs. I need to find a way to guarrantee that overlapping events are visible. By setting up the z-idenx dynamically and the widths.

Comment: @gqstav I added an image that represents the desired outcome